# How would one take a cut of a transaction with Paypal in an asp.net client to client transaction?

Tags: paypal, transactions

Title probably isn't really light shedding, let me rephrase.

On a platform that i have developed in asp.net, A customer can buy a product from an online seller, both of which are from my DataBase, registered users. Now when the customer makes a transaction, i wish to take a 5% cut from the total transaction amount, and the rest is sent to the online seller. I'm not asking for code to do this, but how is this done the correct way theoretically speaking?

Should the payment go to me first, than i split it into 2 payments 5% for me 95% for the seller, or maybe is there some built-in Paypal feature that enables this?

Comment: There are a number of ways to handle this depending on various aspects of your project.  How do you currently have PayPal integrated?  Are you using the Express Checkout API, Adaptive Payments, or what?

Comment: I haven't started yet, I want to understand the theorie before I start to code this part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Express Checkout API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) will give you more freedom to integrate into your application a little more tightly, and the experience for buyers is a little nicer.  It allows you to setup a [parallel payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECParallelPaymens/) where you have multiple receivers on the transaction (with whatever amounts going to each that you specify) but the buyer will be able to see the split during the checkout.

If you want to hide the split you could go with the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/) instead.  Within that, you can do [parallel](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/) or [chained payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/), or even a [delayed chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/).  Chained payments will hide the split from the buyer during checkout, and a delayed chained will be only give the money to the primary receiver until you specify that the secondary payment(s) should be sent by calling the [ExecutePayment API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/).

Yet another option would be to use [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) or Express Checkout to have the money sent to a single account, and then you could forward any payments necessary using the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) just for a single payment.  This can be automated from within an [IPN solution](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

I realize that's a pretty broad answer, but it really was a pretty broad question.